# DeviceReduceModule can't find the IL file

Tags: aleagpu

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Alea.CUDA.IL.CIRCallInstructionBuilder' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Alea.IL, Version=2.1.2.3274, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba52afc3c2e933d6' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The above is the relevant snippet. I am guessing I did not setup Alea correctly, but the troublesome thing is that everything else works for me perfectly. Only this piece of code below throws an exception.

```
let absoluteSumModule = (new DeviceReduceModule<float32>(GPUModuleTarget.Worker(worker), fun a b -> abs(a)+abs(b))).Create(hidden_layer_width*dtest_data.num_rows)
```

I am doing all my work in F# Scripting mode and here is how I set it up.

```
#I @"C:\F# Packages\packages\Alea.CUDA.2.1.2.3274\private"
#I @"C:\F# Packages\packages\Alea.CUDA.2.1.2.3274\lib\net40"
#I @"C:\F# Packages\packages\Alea.CUDA.IL.2.1.2.3274\lib\net40"
#I @"C:\F# Packages\packages\Alea.CUDA.Unbound.2.1.2.3274\lib\net40"
#r @"Alea.CUDA.Unbound.dll"
#r @"Alea.CUDA.IL.dll"
#r @"Alea.CUDA.dll"
#r @"Alea.CUDA.CT.Native.X86.B64.Windows.dll"
#r "System.Configuration.dll"
```

My own code, CuBlas, Unbound's random modules, Unbound's block reduce and scan, and the `DeviceSumModuleF32` work for me. I tried pointing the `Alea.CUDA.Settings.Instance.Resource.AssemblyPath` and `Alea.CUDA.Settings.Instance.Resource.Path` at various library directories, but that does not seem to be doing anything at all. Not having it set at all for the past few weeks did not hinder me. I haven't touched the app.config file because I am not sure how to configure it and am not that comfortable editing config files by hand.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you miss loading `Alea.IL.dll`. `Alea.CUDA.Unbound` depends on `Alea.CUDA.IL`, and `Alea.CUDA.IL` depends on `Alea.CUDA` AND `Alea.IL`. See [here](http://quantalea.com/static/app/manual/compilation-installation.html) for more information.

In your fsx file, you can try add `Alea.IL`, and you don't need reference Alea.CUDA.CT.XXXX, just point the Resource.AssemblyPath to that private folder is enough.

Comment: This fixes my problem regarding finding the IL file. It seems I did not see that there was a second IL directory. That having said, the reduce module now throws a different exception. It still does not work for me. Please see the other question.